# Why did Lord Krishna pick up the Govardhan Hill only with his little finger?

Tags: krishna

Lord Krishna pick up the Govardhana Hill and saved Vrindavan from the wrath of Indra deva, But the use of an only little finger there is any specific reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lord lifted the Govardhana Hill with one hand and not only with one finger, this is mentioned in [SB 10.25.19](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/25/19):

> ity uktva**ikena hastena**
>
> kṛtvā govardhanācalam
>
> dadhāra līlayā viṣṇuś
>
> chatrākam iva bālakaḥ
>
> Having said this, Lord Kṛṣṇa, who is Viṣṇu Himself, picked up Govardhana Hill with **one hand** and held it aloft just as easily as a child holds up a mushroom.

The commentary also says that

> It is confirmed in the Hari-vaṁśa that Śrī Kṛṣṇa picked up the Govardhana Mountain with His left hand.

---

Related Post(s)

[What is the story about Shri Krishna lifting Govardhan Giri to save the villagers from heavy rain?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23995/what-is-the-story-about-shri-krishna-lifting-govardhan-giri-to-save-the-villager/23996#23996)

Comment: please see that  https://youtu.be/C6epbp4RGpc?t=65 and also see various image and you can see that only little finger are used to pick up Govardhan hill

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya Not sure about Videos, images but if it is mentioned in some scriptures then we can dive deep...**SB 10.26.3** and **SB 10.26.25** also mention one hand...

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya It seems few translators have put "little finger" in bracket like this "he held up the mountains of Govardhana (on his little finger)" in the translation of this verse "govardhano dhāritaś ca gavārthe bharatarṣabha" of Mahabharata...But sanskrit verse doesn't mention finger...

Comment: @YDSI see in many pictures and videos Lord Krishna pick up the Govardhan Hill only with his little finger. But according to your answer with a reference I believe that Govardhan raises the mountain with one hand.